# Angular improve my code with $q

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, wordpress, asynchronous

i try to understand $q , i write code to get data from wordpress api v2:
with $http service! it work fine but i understand this code wrong because
i need asynchronous code. so please help me to improve my code

```
myApp.controller('mainCtrl',['$scope','$http',function($scope,$http){
    $scope.myposts = [];


 function sort (){
     $http.get('http://www.ipets.co.il/jobs/wp-json/wp/v2/posts').success(function(posts){
                 angular.forEach(posts , function(post,key){
                     $http.get('http://www.ipets.co.il/jobs/wp-json/wp/v2/media/'+post.featured_media
).success(function(media){

                    var postObj = {}
                        postObj.id = post.id
                        postObj.title = post.title.rendered
                        postObj.image = media.source_url
                        $scope.myposts.push(postObj)

                    // console.log($scope.myposts)

            })

                })


        })  
} 
sort();
console.log($scope.myposts)
}]);
```

Results (console):

```
[ ]
0: Object:
  id:19
  image:"http://ipets.co.il/jobs/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/588.jpg"
  title:"דרוש מלצר/ית לאולם ארועים ״נסיה״"
1: Object:
  id:14
  image:url
  title:title
```

my result it fine! but i know my way is wrong 
because when i call "console.log($scope.myposts)" , is not finish to get all data.

i understand from internet search , i need to use $q service.
but i dont know how it will be in my code.
some one can help me?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a Service that does what you need, controllers must be include only the Business Logic that is required by the view.

I mocked your apis, this example requires a bit of time to be rendered... wait, it works.

```js
function PostsServiceFactory($http, $q) {
  //const POSTS_API = 'http://www.ipets.co.il/jobs/wp-json/wp/v2/posts';
  //const MEDIA_API = 'http://www.ipets.co.il/jobs/wp-json/wp/v2/media/';
  
  // MOCK YOUR API WITH JSON FAKE
  const FAKE = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com"
  const POSTS_API = `${FAKE}/posts`;
  const MEDIA_API = `${FAKE}/photos`;
  
  this.getPosts = function() {
    return $http
      .get(POSTS_API)
      .then(result => result.data)
      .then(posts => $q.all(posts.map(post => {
        let media = post.featured_media || ""; 
      
        return $http
          .get(`${MEDIA_API}${media}`)
          .then(result => result.data)
          .then(media => {
            return {
              "id": post.id,
              "title": post.title,
              "image": media.url
            };
          })
        ;
      })))
    ;
  }
}

function TestCtrl($scope, PostsService) {
  $scope.posts = "LOADING...";
  PostsService
    .getPosts()
    .then((posts) => {
      $scope.posts = posts;
    })
  ;
}

angular
  .module('test', [])
  .service("PostsService", ["$http", "$q", PostsServiceFactory])
  .controller("TestCtrl", ["$scope", "PostsServiceFactory", TestCtrl])
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<section ng-app="test">
  <article ng-controller="TestCtrl">
    <div ng-bind="posts | json"></div>
  </article>
</section>
```

Comment: It work Fine! thank you.  I have 2 questions: 1) what you mean when you use => ?! ... 2) $q.all ?! and "let" ? sorry i think you use Jquery if you can explain your way it will help me more

Comment: That's not jQuery ar all... Have a look at ecmascript6, arrow functions, block scope declarations, promises ... If you want to stay es5 you need for a transpirer or change let with var, arrow functions with functions (be careful with function scopes)

Comment: thank you hitmands i learn more thing about es6 , ok i convert this code to es5 and it work fine , please some one can explain me what the $q.all do in this code?

Comment: posts.map returns an array of promises and $q.all waits for their fulfillment